# s6 camera tremble

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Samsung galaxy s6 with android 6.0.1 and I have a little problem with the camera. While I focus, sometime it trembles. If a take the picture it isn't damaged but it is a bit pesky.
Is it a commom problem? Can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the data of the application. I had this problem and I solved it in this way.